# Java UnknownHostException when parsing an IP Address?

Tags: java, android, networking

I have the following code:

```
String ip = "192.168.1.1";
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
```

When executed on Android (and yes, the manifest contains INTERNET) I sometimes get

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "192.168.1.1": No address associated with hostname
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:289)
```

The documentation on InetAddress suggests that passing in an IP address instead of a hostname is perfectly legal.

There shouldn't be any DNS lookups happening here, so what's going wrong??

Edit:

All very good questions.

This is not being run on an emulator. It's run on live client devices. When bad things happen my code phones home with the details.

I know for certain that this is a Wifi network and not 3G or otherwise.

The first line of code above is just there for illustration. The actual code determines that the Android device runs on the a.b.c.x local network and wants to determine whether there is anything running on a.b.c.1.

The point is that the ip variable is set to a valid IPv4 address. Whether anything runs on it or whether the android device can even see that address is irrelevant. There need not be any hostname resolution as the error message suggests.

One more thing: my app is being run thousands of times a day all around the world without any problem. In a week I'll get a handful of these errors. This means that this code is generally solid and something really bizarre is happening here.

Comment: I suppose you are running this code in Android emulator ?   If so, it should be `10.0.2.2`

Comment: It would be interesting to know if network state makes a predictable difference - do you _always_ get it if you're on 3G, not wifi? (e.g. is Android figuring out that you can't hit a 192.168.0.1 address?).  Does having no network make a difference?  This code suggest any exception in the os layer results in an UnknownHostException: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/2496a68/luni/src/main/java/java/net/InetAddress.java (about line #412)